# How to find the address at which Docker container is available in windows?

Tags: docker

Using docker toolbox on windows 7
There are two images:

1. pg - dB(Postgre);
2. app - debian with django application, the image of which is built from

dockerFile - at the end of which the dev server is started

```
CMD ["python","./vfnd/manage.py","runserver", "0.0.0.0:8001"])
```

Create/start the container as follows

```
docker run -d --name pg_1 pg
docker run -d -p 8001:8001 --link pg_1 --name app_1 app
```

I check through 'ps' - containers are started:

```
app_1 PORT 0.0.0.0:8001->8001; 
pg_1 PORT 5432
```

If you do run app_1 flag-it is visible print - the django dev server is running on 0.0.0.0:8001

On linux django application will be available at 127.0.0.1:8001
But on windows with localhost, the situation is different and it is recommended to run a command that will return the container address

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" app_1
```

But it returns "no value".
Docker inspect outputs the following:
[Docker inspect outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Srdd.jpg)

Tried to pass on 172.17.0.3:8001(from Networks -> IP Address) but the page is not found.
What am I doing wrong? How do I know which address the container is available at?

Comment: You should never run that `docker inspect` command.  The IP address it returns is totally useless in many environments, including your Docker Toolbox setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Docker Toolbox IP address like this :

1. open a terminal.
2. run this command : `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`
3. run this command : `docker-machine ip default`

Comment: Result of eval command "Docker-machine 'dev' does not exist "

Comment: Used 192.168.99.100:8001 and Successfully

Comment: @mr.Di, sorry for that I mean `default`